# Singleton Implementation in Perl 6

Tags: singleton, raku

What is the correct implementation of singleton pattern in perl6?

I've tried this but I dont' know how to use static keyword in perl6:

Comment: I'm no perl guru, but it seems your code lacks a closing '}'.

Comment: fixed, but anyway this typo doesn't fix my problem

Comment: This solution fails with `Too many positionals passed; expected 1 argument but got 2` in perl6 2018.03.

Comment: This code is old I will paste new version as anwser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It one of the few reasons that require using `bless` method

```
class Singleton {
    my Singleton $instance;
    method new {!!!}
    submethod instance {
        $instance = Singleton.bless unless $instance;
        $instance;
    }
 }
```

Comment: I would actually argue that *any* type object is a singleton.  So `class Singleton { }` would be enough to create a `Singleton` type object, of which there can only be one.